# Regular Expressions in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I match a string that does not contain X with ColdFusion regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409065/how-do-i-match-a-string-that-does-not-contain-x-with-coldfusion-regular-expressio)

In ColdFusion version 8, I am building a validation table that contains regular expressions.
Using a regular expression, how do you say:

```
<cfif FIND("X",myString)>
   <cfset returnValue=0>
<cfelse>
   <cfset returnValue=1>
</cfif>
```

Note: The second returnValue can be any value other than zero.

P.S.: When I said "The second returnValue can be any value other than zero", I meant that if it makes it easier to write the regular expression to return something other than 1, then go ahead, because all I'm looking for is whether myString has an X in it or not.