# How do I match a string that does not contain X with ColdFusion regular expressions?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407453/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion) earlier, but it got a negative vote, so I'm rewording it.
I have:

```
<cfset myExpression = "X">
#REFind(myExpression,myString)#
```

I need to change myExpression so that it returns a value other than zero if there is NOT an X in myString, and a 0 if there is an X in myString.

Comment: "The second returnValue can be any value other than zero." -- huh? What value should it be.

Comment: I'm looking for the reverse of REFind("X",myString), but the answer must be within the regular expression.  The answer cannot be: NOT REFind("X",myString).

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for the opposite of its normal behavior. Is this correct? Just read your previous question. Why can the answer not by to add NOT to the expression? Seems like the simplest answer to me.

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether or not myString contains an "X"?  Or is there a particular pattern (not containing X) that you are searching for?

Comment: Phillip, you could have just edited the previous question to be clearer. \*shrug\* It wouldn't surprise me if the negative vote was due to the bad title, which you've repeated here, so I've edited it to actually be what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfset string = "abc" />  
<cfoutput>#refind( "^[^X]+$" , string )#</cfoutput> // 1 

<cfset string = "abcX" /> 
<cfoutput>#refind( "^[^X]+$" , string )#</cfoutput> // 0
```

Comment: IF myString contains "ABC", then the expression returns a value other than zero.
IF myString contains "ABCX", then the expression returns 0.

Comment: <cfset string = "abc" />

<cfoutput>#refind( "^[^X]+$" , string )#</cfoutput> // 1

<cfset string = "abcX" />

<cfoutput>#refind( "^[^X]+$" , string )#</cfoutput> // 0

Comment: By Jove, I think that's it!  I'm looking up what the $ means and will accept this answer in a sec.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the +$ means.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn : The + means one or more of the previous construct.  In this case, it means one or more "not-X".  The $ is the end of the string, similar to ^ being the beginning.

Comment: Keep in mind that "^[^ben]+$" is not the same thing as not finding "ben".  [] indicates you are using a class, not a literal string.  Running the former against "psenn" returns 0, because the 'e's match.

Comment: Oh.  That's a great example. I'll have to remember that if more than one character is being matched.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this answer (`^[^X]+$`) requires at least one character - i.e. an empty string will also return false. Use `^[^X]*$` if you want to allow empty string.

Answer (score 1):

> I am building a validation table

Well, the first thing to check is that you're not re-inventing the wheel - the [isValid](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_in-k_37.html) function can validate a variety of types (creditcard,email,zipcode,etc).

It also provides a way to match against a regex pattern, like this:

```
<cfif isValid('regex',String,RegexPattern) >
```

Something to be aware of: the [documentation for isValid](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_in-k_37.html) claims that it uses JavaScript regex, which (if true) is different to the default Apache ORO regex that CF uses for everything else.

For the direct regex version of what you were doing (which does use Apache ORO), you would use:

```
<cfif refind(RegexPattern,String) >
```

It's not clear what you're on about with your `returnValue` bit, though if you're returning a boolean from a function, ditch the `cfif` and just do one of these instead:

```
<cfreturn isValid('regex',String,RegexPattern) />

<cfreturn refind(RegexPattern,String) />
```

Answer (score 1):

if your expression is always a character or set of characters then you want

`<cfset myExpression ="[^X]">`

Comment: Thanks Lucas!  That's what I thought too!  But [^X] returns the first position of a character that is not X.